# Plotting/Working with 1million nodes

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx, nodes

I am busy with an exercise to plot nodes on a pane. My first goal is to work with 1million nodes and then ramp it up to 15million.

I have a custom Object Graph and I can add edges and nodes to this object. Each node object has an ellipse that I can call and plot and same with the edge objects.
At the moment I have a function that generates a random position for the nodes.

I am using a scroll pane at the moment to enable panning around the pane and to view all the nodes.

What I thought was a good idea was to use a hashmap

```
Map<String, ArrayList<Node>> mapX = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Node>>();
Map<String, ArrayList<Node>> mapY = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Node>>();
```

I use the following code to add nodes to the hashmap:

```
int  tempXFloor = (int)Math.floor(tempX);
ArrayList<Node> tempList = mapX.get(tempXFloor+"");
if(tempList == null){
tempList = new ArrayList<>();
}
tempList.add(node); 
mapX.put(tempXFloor+"",tempList);
```

Then while I am panning I get the current position, floor it and check if an entry exist in the map. if an entry exist, I add all the nodes in the ArrayList to nodesOnScreen.
nodesOnScreen is an ArrayList type, and I will add the nodes to that list while I am panning and likewise the nodes that are off the screen are removed from the nodesOnScreen variable.

I only plot the nodes that is in the ArrayList nodesOnScreen.

I would appreciate some guidance in this matter, and how to handle such big data structures. Am I going in the right direction or am I missing an obvious "trick" to do it.

Comment: I found "Oracle Berkeley DB Java Edition" and would like to know if that is a suitable database to use, or can you recommend one?
Would a binary file also be appropriate to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several points to think about:

1. How complex are your nodes? If they are just dots you may consider drawing them on an [WritableImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/image/WritableImage.html) and save a lot of memory. For more complex cases you may want to use [Canvas](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/canvas/Canvas.html). Either way you will save on event handlers, properties and other small things which counts in larger amounts.
2. Another important matter is relevance of the data view. If you presents a map or something similar then user only care about visible part. The rest can be stored in disk cache and by [Pareto principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_principle) only 20% of that data will be of much use. So you can plan accordingly and have real graphical nodes only for visible part (and maybe preload some adjusted parts for user experience sake).
3. "Divide and conquer" conception. Even if you don't want to restrict user view according to plan (2) you can't be in constant need of 15 millions nodes. Not in UI library, there is no big enough monitors I'm afraid. So, split your data into segments and load one segment in a time. If you need to perform any kind of calculations on the whole set -- do not work with nodes, use simplest implementation and perform calculations in some background process.
4. Existing solutions are always a matter of investigations before doing big stuff. For example, there are a lot of caching libraries like [PojoCache](http://www.samaxes.com/2009/03/jboss-pojocache-configuration/) which seamlessly allow you to work with relevant data only once you splitted your billions of nodes into groups.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The nodes I am working with has quite a lot of event handlers; moving them around, right click to change their attributes and such. All these event handlers is on the ellipse that is part of the node object. The node object also has a ArrayList of all its attributes.
I like the idea of divide and conquer. I have started with it but was reluctant to use a database because I had no guidance, but now I know that it is the right path.

Answer (score 3):

What you want falls into the category of [space partitioning structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_partitioning).

The thing you described is a specialized form of [uniform grids or bins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_%28computational_geometry%29). The general version differs from yours in that each bin may span more than 1 unit in size, and thus is better suited for datasets of different resolutions. Bins are generally useful for datasets which are more or less uniformly distributed, it's also very simple to implement. Finding on-screen elements simply involves finding all the bins that your viewport falls into.

If your dataset is non-uniform, i.e. there's tight clumps and large empty spaces, you might want to try an alternative structure like [quad trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree).

Also, if you are using a hash table or any other java container, use the int by boxing it into an Integer (`Map<Integer, ...>`), don't convert it to a string, which is much slower and consumes more memory.

Comment: Yay for quad trees. Spatial indexing is the OP needs to keep the loaded data to a minimum.

Comment: Thanks for the hashmap tip. I will definitely implement the bins idea and try and store the bins I am not working with in a database. I will have to look into quad trees and see what I can do with them.

Comment: I found Geo4j, A graph based database. Does it sound like a good idea to store all my nodes in a Geo4j database and then use a quad tree to check which nodes I would be needing next?

Comment: Not sure that a graph database optimized for GIS applications is what you need, it's likely overkill. Unless, of course, you are storing something like road data. That said, if you can figure out the API, it probably provides things like KD-trees and maybe even rendering built-in.

Answer (score 2):

You can try build it "on-the-fly" using data virtualization and data provider. Don't use your RAM to hold big data. Use database queries. Implement your List type and implement indexer there, which will return an item from database.

Comment: which database do you recommend? I am using JavaFx-2.

Comment: Try MongoDB with fractal tree indexes. It will provide quick access to your data.

Answer (score 1):

Think about level-of-detail. You cannot possibly see 15M distinct dots on a screen (not enough pixels to make individual node foregrounds visible above the backgrounds). Two types of level-of-detail approaches are available:

- graphical: use a very large canvas (say, 10M x 10M), drawing small tiles (say, 1K x 1K pixels) at a time and down-scaling these to compose the final image (for instance, 1K x 1K -> 10 x 10, twice, allows your 10M x 10M virtual canvas to be down-scaled into a 1K x 1K image).
- semantical: aggregate clumps of nodes into single nodes, and draw the clump-nodes instead of the individual nodes. You can do this at several levels. Indeed, if you plan on drawing graphs, this is exactly what the graph-drawing algorithms will do underneath (no graph drawing algorithm deals with >50K nodes in reasonable times without some sort of hierarchical decomposition).

In both cases, you would supply some sort of zoom and details-on-demand; the main overview would be used only to pan and zoom into particular details. Some sort of spatial index (quad-trees are the most frequent one) would allow you to quickly retrieve tiles from disk or secondary storage. In the semantical-zoom scenario, you would instead add "parent" fields to each node, building a giant (externally serialized; don't load 15M nodes in memory unless you really, really have to) tree of nodes.

Comment: I have started working on algorithms to clump nodes in groups. Still working on it though.